# cannot boot to built-in solid state drive

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, 19.10, initramfs

For two weeks, I have been running sucessfully Ubuntu 19.10 on a newly acquired Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop with a built-in 512 GB M.2 PCIe NVMe solid state drive. Ubuntu 18.04 was preinstalled by Dell, and I immediately installed Ubuntu 19.10 from a USB drive. There was never any other operating system on the laptop. All of a sudden, upon choosing in the GRUB menu any one of the following:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-42-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-40-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-40-generic (recovery mode)
```

I get:

```
[ 0.490531 Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules)
ALERT! UUID=df22e057-0e1c-4faf-8918-394fce7bac20 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

I can proceed as follows.

```
(initramfs) /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=df22e057-0e1c-4faf-8918-394fce7bac20 ro quiet splash
(initramfs)
```

Does any one have an idea how to repair this behaviour?

I cannot reinstall Ubuntu. The installation program tells me that only 8 GB is available, which is the capacity of the USB drive. Also, when I run Ubuntu from the USB drive, the utility program Disks does not show the presence of the built-in 512 GB drive.

Comment: Will the system boot if you are hands-off (no menu selections)?

Comment: No, I cannot boot to the built-in drive in any way.

Comment: My kneejerk reaction is that the drive failed.

Comment: GRUB and the Initramfs are seen to be there, so some information can be extracted from the drive.

Comment: Problem solved thanks Dell Support. Somehow 'RAID ON' had been set in the BIOS.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Riccardo, my solution in this case was much simpler: Just shifting the BIOS variable 'SATA Operation' from 'RAID On' to 'AHCI'. This brought back my internal drive including everything I installed during the first 1 1/2 week of my possession. Now my system just works fine.

Apparently, 'RAID On' is Dell's default, but there are indications concerning a related model and a different Linux distribution that this is not optimal with Linux:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(7390)

Notice the sentence:

> In order for Linux to see the internal NVMe SSD, it must be changed in the BIOS from the default "RAID mode" to "AHCI mode".

Comment: Good, thanks for sharing, can be helpful!  Greetings, @neergard

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Fedora user from many years; the following is the sequence of steps that I do to install it on a laptop, that can help you with little chances:

1) setup a bootable usb with your distro. Fedora has a [tool](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/) for that; I'm sure there is something similar for Ubuntu.

2) go into your laptop BIOS settings to enable the boot from usb

3) boot the live distro from your usb

4) backup any data of the old OS on an external hd

5) setup the internet connection and install gparted; on Fedora: `sudo dnf install gparted`

6) open `gparted` tool, select the drive where you desire to install the OS, after completed your data backup. If you desire to install only Linux distro, setup the disk just deleting any old partition

7) after that hd reset, create a new GTP partition table and you have done!

8) at this point, install the distro from the live running distro; Fedora has a shortcut on its desktop for that. There will be something similar in Ubuntu.

9) use the user interface of the distro installer to select language, keyboard language, timezone, the drive where to install the distro

10) create the partitions by using the installer's user interface; essentially one for `/boot/efi`, one for `/` and one for `linux-swap`

11) following the installer, you have to create a password for root and a user that you can add to `wheel` group to enable it for `sudo`

12) wait the end of installation with the creation of grub entries

13) the installer will say to reboot: do it removing the usb

Hope this can guide you. I'm really fine with **[Fedora XFCE](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/xfce/)**, one of its [spins](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/). You can always add Compiz, for example, after and [customize](https://youtu.be/x8wW0cdEJHc) it ([here](https://www.opendesktop.org/u/mitma/) some Emerald themes that I created). You have to change the package manager command from `apt-get` to `dnf` and `-dev` packages with `-devel`, essentially.

Cheers